# $x$ in group G with order $r$, $y$ in group $G'$ with order $s$ what is the order of $(x,y)$ in $G$ x $G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have an element $x$ of order $r$ in a group $G$ and an element $y$ in group $G'$ of order $s$. Is the order of $(x,y)$ in the product group $G$ x $G'$ $lcm(r,s)$?

**Thoughts**: I think that this is true, but I am not sure if this only applies to cyclic groups.

Comment: Yes it is. You need $x^m = e$ and $y^m = e$. The smallest such $m$ is the lcm by definition.

Comment: Thanks you sir, and if r and s are relatively prime then rs is the order

Comment: Correct! $\,\,\,$

Comment: I should note that $r$ must divide $m$ and same goes for $s$. I will leave you to prove that if you have not done so already. This is why you get the lcm.

Comment: Thanks sir! I see why that is true!!!!!