# What is the definition of the least common multiple of elements of a group rather than their orders?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, permutations, least-common-multiple

In an answer to my question here [Relationship between order of $(x,y)$ in $G \times G'$ and order of disjoint permutations, which both involve LCMs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954852/relationship-between-order-of-x-y-in-g-times-g-and-order-of-disjoint-per), it is said that

> Let $G$ be a group, $a\in G$ of order $r$ and $b\in G$ of order $s$.
>
> If $ab=ba$, then the order of $ab$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.

I submitted an edit to change this to $\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)$, but I was denied. Here is the denial: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1085060 Later this was edited by José Carlos Santos into the current revision. Here is the edit into the current revision: https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2954951/2

The one who is answered is Scientifica. I asked him/her what $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$. The reply was

> @JackBauer It means "the least common multiple of a and b". You used it yourself in your question ;)

1. What is the definition of the least common multiple of elements of a group? I could not find this online. I thought LCM was for integers under the addition operation and under the usual topology on $\mathbb Z$ (and under the usual everything in every branch of mathematics).
2. Where did I use the concept of least common multiple of elements of a group in my question?

Comment: Scientifica has now clarified that your suggested edit was correct (the rejection must have been a mistake). There is no such thing as least common multiple in a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as least common multiple in a *group*. Every element of a group is a multiple of every other element.